# Staying in Canada beyond eTA and passport expiration

Tags: passports, canada, eta

Is it allowed to stay in Canada beyond the date on which an eTA (and the passport it is linked to) expires?

I haven't yet entered, so it's hypothetical, but if I wasn't limited by CBSA on entry I would be allowed to stay for 6 months. If my passport and eTA expired in a month from my date of entry, could I still stay for 6 months?

Comment: @ChrisH I read that question but it's more general as it doesn't address the case of an eTA that is expiring in less than 6 months.

Comment: I think the answer does cover it, but it would be good to see a better/clearer answer.

To help with the question, could you clarify how long you were given to remain in Canada upon entry, and when that will run out.

Comment: @CMaster added an example

Comment: @yannis I don’t know if citizenship makes a difference,  but based on eg UK government travel advice for Canada, your passport should be valid for the proposed duration of your stay. So I think the answer is ‘no’ but others with better knowledge will likely provide a definitive answer.

Comment: @CMaster I suspect that the visit necessarily would be limited to the validity of the passport, in which case the answers to the linked question are insufficient because they do not discuss conditions under which limiting the visit to less than six months' duration would be mandatory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your ETA needs only to be valid on the day of entry. Of course, to avoid unforeseen itinerary changes, you should always renew beforehands if you expect to travel to Canada near or after the expiry.

However, the general rule that the passport should be valid for the whole of expected stay (for short-term visitors) **still applies** independent of eTA (except that the eTA also expires with the passport).

> **How long can I stay in Canada as a visitor?**
>
> Most visitors can stay for up to 6 months in Canada.
>
> At the port of entry, the border services officer may allow you to
> stay for less or more than 6 months. If so, they’ll put the date you
> need to leave by in your passport. They might also give you a
> document.
>
> If you don’t get a stamp in your passport, you can stay for 6 months
> from the day you entered Canada or **until your passport expires,
> whichever comes first.**
>
> https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1016

(Note that no mention of the validity of visitor visa or eTA is mentioned in the FAQ answer)

As explained in the answer to the other question, eTA is only an pre-entry authorization for air travel only, independent of the purpose or duration of the actual stay which is examined at the border and subject to usual rules (e.g. up to six months of stay for visitors).

Assuming you are a foreign national subject to eTA, you would technically need one also even if you have an approved work and student permit (even if you will stay beyond the eTA or passport validity for study or work as it is often the case). The eTA in this case is automatically granted with the approval of the permit, however.

Similar principle applies to visitor visa:

> **Must I leave Canada by the valid until date on my visitor visa?**
>
> No. The date on the visitor visa is the date by which you must arrive in Canada.
>
> https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=442&top=16

Comment: "You would need one also even if you have an approved work and student permit": really?  As far as I'm aware, someone with a work or study permit does not require eTA, which is only for non-US citizens who don't need and don't have a visa.

Comment: @phoog They need one, but it is automatically granted without additional fee with the approval/renewal of the permit ("combined application"). This would be purely technical if not for that the granted eTA is not tied to the permit, you can still use it to visit after study/work ends (within five years/expiry of passport).

Comment: I see, thank you.  I looked a bit at this distinction between visas on one hand and work permits and study permits on the other, and as far as I could tell this means that students and workers have to renew their stay every six months if they don't leave the country.  Is that correct?  It seems burdensome and expensive for (for example) a doctoral candidate who might remain in Canada for several years.

Comment: @phoog The study permit can be issued for expected duration of study (subject to passport expiry). It allows legal stay in Canada as long as the permit is valid. If a visa national leaves Canada during the permit validity but the visa expired or the passport changed (renewal of study permit doesn't include a new visitor visa, only an eTA for non-visa nationals), they would need to reapply for a visitor visa before being let back in (except for visit to US or SPM where study permit alone is enough for renetry). But now with 10-year visa being the norm this is not a big problem usually.

Comment: @zhantongz do you know if I could stay for the whole 6 months if I were planning to renew my passport in Canada/had applied for a renewal before entering?

Comment: @yannis You would need to convince the border officer to give you a separate visitor record with specific date instead of the default. It will be hard to do so without good reason. Passport renewal is out of Canada's control.

Comment: If you want to stay for six months I **strongly** recommend getting your passport renewed before you arrive.

Comment: While a visitor to Canada one can request an extension to one's stay by applying for a [visitor record](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/extend-stay.html). I recall reading of someone who obtained a visitor record that allowed them to extend their stay to attend a planned family gathering.